# Resize the Jumbotron element from Bootstrap to fit the width of screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm using this jumbotron instance on my site and I want to use the jumbotron fluid as per the documentation so as to resize/fit my complete jumbotron to screen width. But I cannot increase its width for some reason.

Below is my code

```js
    $(".jumbotron").css({ height: $(window).height() + "px" });
    
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      $(".jumbotron").css({ height: $(window).height() + "px" });
    });
    $(".form-control").click(function(){
      $(this).prev().val("");
    document.getElementById("inzone").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("outzone").style.display = 'block';
    
    });
```

```css
    .jumbotron {
      color: white;
      background-image: url("picture link");
      background-position: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      
     }
     
    
    .wrap{
      width: 60%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        
    <div class="wrap">
       <div style="text-align: center;"><label style="font-weight:bold;">Select your location to find best offers available:</label></div>
    <div class="form-froup">
    <div class="input-icons">
    <i class="fa fa-search icon"></i>
      <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Enter Area Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
           
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is inzone and outzone here? can you please add complete html code?

Comment: I dropped the code in codepen and it appears to be working well. Can you clarify what width needs to be increased? https://codepen.io/ladywebhawk/pen/jOqLdRg

Answer (score 0):

I think this code may be help you.
I use a big grey box as Jumbotron.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .jumbotron{
            position: relative;
            top: 200px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .wrap{
            width: 60%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div style="text-align: center;"><label style="font-weight:bold;">Select your location to find best offers available:</label></div>
            <div class="form-froup">
                <div class="input-icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-search icon"></i>
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Enter Area Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".jumbotron").css({ height: $(window).height() + "px" });

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        $(".jumbotron").css({ height: $(window).height() + "px" });
    });
    $(".form-control").click(function(){
        $(this).prev().val("");
        document.getElementById("inzone").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("outzone").style.display = 'block';

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```